# This code implemented in kotlin gives an error message-"Unresolved reference text". I am a beginner and just started with android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, textview

```
fun onButtonClicked(view: View) {
    val randomNumber=(1..6).random()
    TextView.text=randomNumber.toString()
}
```

Comment: There are so many text views, you have to point to a specific TextView, aka an object of a text view, you can do as Saurabh suggested. :^)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to direct set text on `TextView` class. You have to use an object of that class, particularly on that object which is in your layout. Use `findViewById()` to find that `TextView` to which you want to set that random number to.

```
fun onButtonClicked(view: View) {
    val randomNumber=(1..6).random()
    val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.your_textview_id)
    textView.text = randomNumber.toString()
}
```